# Flash CS6 error 1120: Access of undefined property (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compiler-errors, undefined

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to make a symbol move in flash CS6, using AS3.

I used code snippets for the arrow key movement, but there it all went wrong. I always get error -> access of undefined property movement. 
[image]

This is the part of code where the problems occurs.
[image]

What am I overlooking? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the `movement` Variable set for the first time?

Comment: Where is the code shown in relation to your movement instance?  Can you post your .fla file to a cloud storage service and share?  this would make is much easier to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you did not set the instance name of the symbol as movement. check that please.

Comment: I changed everything to instance name "movement".. :s

Comment: This is a very low quality answer.  Consider making it a comment instead.

Comment: i am sorry for that but i can not post comment so i post it as answer.